# Show that $ |a_n| \leq 2(1-\alpha)$ for every $n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $g(z)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ is analytic for $|z|<1$, with $Re(g(z))> \alpha$. Show that $ |a_n| \leq 2(1-\alpha)$ for every $n$.

**Answer:**

Since $Re(g(z))>\alpha$ implies $g(z)$ is bounded, say $|g(z)|>\alpha$.

Then,

$g(z)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^n \\ \Rightarrow |g(z)| \leq 1+ \sum |a_nz^n|  $

any hints for showing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is using Carathéodory lemma, since for
$$\dfrac{g(z)-\alpha}{1-\alpha}=1+\sum_{n\geqslant1}\dfrac{a_n}{1-\alpha}z^n$$
we have ${\bf Re}\dfrac{g(z)-\alpha}{1-\alpha}>0$ where $\alpha<1$, then $\dfrac{g(z)-\alpha}{1-\alpha}$ is subordinate to $\dfrac{1+z}{1-z}$, and Carathéodory lemma says for such function $\left|\dfrac{a_n}{1-\alpha}\right|\leqslant2$.